# “He Loves.” A Complete Sentence, and Grammatical?

Tags: transitivity

> He loves.

I’ve read some things about intransitive verbs, recently. Can “*He loves*”. be thought of as a complete sentence, and grammatical?

And, can

> A wind comes.

and

> He has.

be thought of as complete sentences, and both grammatical?

Comment: I've heard the expression 'He loves' in a fictional reported conversation where a person explains that man loves a woman but does not speak of it to her. It seemed to be a kind of 'shorthand' for 'he loves her'. 'He has' would be a correct conversational answer to a question beginning 'Has he...?'.

Comment: Generally speaking you have to check a dictionary to see if the usage you want is an intransitive verb. If so, then technically it is OK but may not make sense as is. BTW, *to have* is not intransitive.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear what's being asked. There are various definitions of *complete sentence* and widely varying ideas of what constitutes a sentence, even among linguists. I've asked you to specify what you mean in your earlier post on the same topic, referenced above. Do some research on "sentence". Read the wikipedia article on the topic, and [this](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/senterm.htm). Be more specific in your questions. Explain the thinking behind them. Do you believe "He loves" can be a sentence? Can you imagine how it would be used? What it would mean?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the verb "loves" takes an explicit object. But it is not necessarily so. For example, some theists might answer the question:

> What does God do?

by saying

> He loves

In any case "he loves" is a full sentence.

Comment: What is a *full sentence?* Is there such thing as a *partial sentence?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your examples are complete sentences and grammatically correct. Contexts in which these sentences would sound natural may be rare to nonexistent, but syntactically they're fine.

*He has* doesn't usually work as an intransitive construction, but it works as an example of ellipsis (omission). E.g.:

> "Has your brother cleaned his room?"
>
> "He has [cleaned his room]."

Comment: I see. I thank you. So *have* seems transitive. So, I may not use it like that. And, “*A wind comes.*” may work, too?

Comment: Iolanthe's ballad in Act II of _Iolanthe_ by W S Gilbert and Sir Arthur Sullivan begins and ends with the sentence "He loves!". [See no. 44](https://archive.org/stream/iolantheorpeera00gilbgoog/iolantheorpeera00gilbgoog_djvu.txt)

Comment: Actually, "He has" can work as a transitive: "Who here has a smartphone with them? He has!" (pointing).

Comment: Your paragraph *Yes, your examples are complete sentences and grammatically correct. Contexts in which these sentences would sound natural may be rare to nonexistent, but syntactically they're fine.* can also be said of *A star shoots*, which is why I've voted this question as a duplicate.

Comment: -1 Dictionary.com have  verb (used without object), present singular 1st person have, 2nd have or (Archaic) hast, 3rd has or (Archaic) hath, present plural have; past singular 1st person had, 2nd had or (Archaic) hadst or haddest, 3rd had, past plural had; past participle had; present participle having.
24.
to be in possession of money or wealth:
*There are some who have and some who have not.*

Answer (score -1):

`To love` is **not** intransitive, nor is it ditransitive.  Aside from religious lingo, most people who hear the "sentence"

> He loves.

...will feel lost and be anticipating a direct object.

I'm curious.  In what context are trying to use such a "sentence?"

#### No, it's not correct / grammatical.

You're other two example sentences, however, are absolutely correct!

Although, your third sentence.

> He has.

requires a context in the perfect tense.

> Has Joe eaten?
>
> He has.

On the *other* hand, if you simply say.

> He has.

Listeners will immediately anticipate the question

> He has what?

---

`To come` is **intransitive** and doesn't require or expect a direct object.  If anything, it may expect a destination, or an entire clause.

> - He comes bearing gifts.
> - They came riding in on horseback.
> - You come along.
> - The wind comes.  // Better to say the wind is coming, but still it's correct.

Comment: -1 American Heritage Dictionary: v.intr. To feel love or sexual love for another. // Merriam-Webster online dictonary: intransitive verb
:  to feel affection or experience desire // Dictionary.com: verb (used without object), loved, loving. 21. to have love or affection for another person; be in love.