# What May a Complete Interrogative Seek?

Tags: interrogatives

> He does?
>
> He ran?

I think I read a complete interrogative requests a subject, and verb. So, may I use these two sentences, and have them grammatically all right?

Comment: I notice that you've asked very similar questions several times before:  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80675/a-complete-interrogative-sentence-grammatically-proper-like-a-complete-declara, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79375/is-the-sentence-a-star-shoots-grammatical, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79871/he-loves-a-complete-sentence-and-grammatical  Is there something that the previous answers didn't cover?

Answer (score 1):

These aren't complete sentences. But they would be understood and accepted as responses to a statement indicating that you find it unlikely or surprising.

> Alice: Bob likes Mexican food.
>
> Carl: He does?

Carl is saying that he is surprised that Bob likes Mexican food, or that he doesn't think that this statement is true.

But it's not a complete sentence. A complete sentence would be something like:

> Does Bob like Mexican food?

Comment: So, I guess, a complete interrogative may not request a subject, and verb. It seems, here, that a complete interrogative requests an auxiliary verb(?), argument, verb, and, maybe, other arguments. May you get to use *Does he run?*, and have it grammatically proper?

Comment: The general form of an interrogative sentence is [interrogative word (who/what/where/why/how] [helping verb (usually is/does)] [subject] [verb] [object], like "What do dogs eat?" The interrogative word can be omitted for yes/no questions, like "Is Jack here?" or "Do birds fly?" Yes, "Does he run?" is a perfectly grammatical sentence. You could debate if one-word questions like "Who?" are complete sentences. I'd say no, but they're common and generally understood in context.